# Cordova push notification plugin?

Tags: cordova

When I sent a push message to the device, I could receive the message on my iPhone. I touched the

message to open the application but the event $cordovaPush:notificationReceived did not work. I

handle this event to get message data which includes title, body and custom data. I used Parse.com to

send push message. I wonder if you could tell what wrong with my code?

Comment: You should show the part of your code that is not working properly.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I'm processing completed.